# Merge two SQL queries in the same resultset

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to execute this four queries and report the results in a single table.

```
Q1: select openedDays as crit  from issues_summary where severity="CRITICAL" 
Q1: select openedDays as maj  from issues_summary where severity="MAJOR" 
Q1: select openedDays as blocker  from issues_summary where severity="BLOCKER" 
Q1: select openedDays as minor  from issues_summary where severity="MINOR"
```

The result of each query is one single column as example:

```
CRIT
11
23
35
54
34
```

Is it possible to run all the queries together to get this result?

```
BLOCK | CRIT | MAJ | MIN
11    | 23   | 13  | 17
23    | 45   | 34  | 33
...
```

Comment: You would need to give us some relation between the columns to generate your expected output.  SQL generally isn't good at just sticking data together as you have done.

Comment: The table from which I am running the query has this structure: 

      issue_name      | severity | openedDays 
      squid:S00105 | MINOR | 6
      squid:S135       | MINOR | 6
      squid:S00105   | MINOR | 0
      squid:S00105   | MINOR | 26
      squid:MethodCyclomaticComplexity |  CRITICAL | 133
      squid:S1166   |  MAJOR | 133
      squid:MethodCyclomaticComplexity | CRITICAL | 107
      squid:S1181 | MAJOR | 305 
      squid:S00105 | MINOR | 412

Comment: Is there any connection between the values in one output row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregating a CASE WHEN works on most databases, including Sqlite.

```
select 
SUM(case when severity = 'BLOCKER' then openedDays end) as BLOCK,
SUM(case when severity = 'CRITICAL' then openedDays end) as CRIT,
SUM(case when severity = 'MAJOR' then openedDays end) as MAJ,
SUM(case when severity = 'MINOR' then openedDays end) as MIN
from issues_summary 
where severity in ('BLOCKER','CRITICAL','MAJOR','MINOR')
```

But without a GROUP BY on some column(s) that would only generate one line.

**Returns:**

```
BLOCK CRIT MAJ MIN
----- ---- --- ---
   34   68  47  50
```

If there's no such column(s) to group on?
Then one could be creative and simulate a partitioned ROW_NUMBER.
And then group on that calculated row_number.

```
SELECT 
  MAX(case when severity = 'BLOCKER' then openedDays end) as BLOCK,
  MAX(case when severity = 'CRITICAL' then openedDays end) as CRIT,
  MAX(case when severity = 'MAJOR' then openedDays end) as MAJ,
  MAX(case when severity = 'MINOR' then openedDays end) as MIN
FROM (
   select severity, openedDays,
  (select count(*) FROM issues_summary t2 WHERE t2.severity = t.severity AND t2.openedDays <= t.openedDays) as ROWNUM
  from issues_summary t
  where severity in ('BLOCKER','CRITICAL','MAJOR','MINOR')
) q
GROUP BY ROWNUM
ORDER BY BLOCK, CRIT, MAJ, MIN
```

**Returns:**

```
BLOCK CRIT MAJ MIN
----- ---- --- ---
   11   23  13  17
   23   45  34  33
```

But that trick can be a performance killer.

Here's another more roundabout way.
By creating temporary tables for each severity, and one for ID's.
And then linking those on the same ID.
Even if some openedDays appear more than once per severity, then those duplicates will also show up in the result.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_block;
create TEMPORARY table tmp_block (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, openedDays int);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_crit;
create TEMPORARY table tmp_crit (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, openedDays int);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_maj;
create TEMPORARY table tmp_maj (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, openedDays int);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_min;
create TEMPORARY table tmp_min (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, openedDays int);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_id;
create TEMPORARY table tmp_id (ID INTEGER);

insert into tmp_block (openedDays) SELECT openedDays FROM issues_summary WHERE severity = 'BLOCKER' ORDER BY openedDays;
insert into tmp_crit (openedDays) SELECT openedDays FROM issues_summary WHERE severity = 'CRITICAL' ORDER BY openedDays;
insert into tmp_maj (openedDays) SELECT openedDays FROM issues_summary WHERE severity = 'MAJOR' ORDER BY openedDays;
insert into tmp_min (openedDays) SELECT openedDays FROM issues_summary WHERE severity = 'MINOR' ORDER BY openedDays;

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT count(*) AS MaxCnt
  FROM issues_summary
  GROUP BY severity
  ORDER BY count(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
,RCTE AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS ID, MaxCnt 
  FROM CTE
  union ALL
  SELECT ID + 1, MaxCnt
  FROM RCTE WHERE ID < MaxCnt
)
INSERT INTO tmp_id (ID)
SELECT ID 
FROM RCTE;

select 
tmp_block.openedDays as BLOCK,
tmp_crit.openedDays as CRIT,
tmp_maj.openedDays as MAJ,
tmp_min.openedDays as MIN
FROM tmp_id
LEFT JOIN tmp_block ON tmp_block.id = tmp_id.id
LEFT JOIN tmp_crit ON tmp_crit.id = tmp_id.id
LEFT JOIN tmp_maj ON tmp_maj.id = tmp_id.id
LEFT JOIN tmp_min ON tmp_min.id = tmp_id.id
ORDER BY tmp_id.id;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have colums for group on. 

What I need is the list of all values (I need to use them for statistical  analysis). 
THe trick I found not is to get all the results of the first query and paste them in one excel column, get the results of all the other queries and paste in the other columns and then export back the csv from excel. 
The problem is that this trick is not easy to automate and I am looking for a direct SQL approach

Comment: @Botacco  If it's for a statistical purposes, then the second query might not be the solution you need either. Because for example if there are more than 1 of the same value for a severity? Then that value will only appear once in the result.  So a count for that value based on the result would be wrong. Then perhaps dragging a `select serverity, openedDays from issues_summary where severity in (...)` would be more accurate. And make Excel analyse that.

Comment: @Botacco  I've added a 3th solution to the answer.  More code (hurts my golfcoding instincts) , but it should be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you just want to merge result sets, then you could take a look at the [union [all] command](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-union/)
If the data is linked, you'll need a join.